# Как сделать валидация input, что бы только цифры и (!одна) точка или запятая была?

Tags: javascript, валидация

Помогите доработать регулярное выражение, чтобы с помощью JS и RegExp (наверное) сделать валидацию поля input так, что бы вводились только цифры или одна точка или одна запятая.
(если есть точка запятой не может быть и наоборот)

Вот пока моё решение на данный момент:

```js
 document.getElementById("#checkIt").onclick = function() {
   alert('Рез-т -    ' + /^\s*[\d]+(?:,[\d]+)?\s*$/.test(document.getElementById("#inputIn").value));
 }
```

```html
<input id="#inputIn" />
<button id="#checkIt">check</button>
```

Ссылка на jsfiddle:
[туц](https://jsfiddle.net/_jack/bgs7n895/11/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
 document.getElementById("#checkIt").onclick = function() {
   alert('Рез-т - ' + /^\s*\d*[\.\,]?\d*\s*$/.test(document.getElementById("#inputIn").value));
 }
```

```html
<input id="#inputIn" />
<button id="#checkIt">check</button>
```

если хотите чтобы точку нельзя было поставить в начале или в конце тогда так

```js
 document.getElementById("#checkIt").onclick = function() {
   alert('Рез-т - ' + /^\s*\d+[\.\,]?\d+\s*$/.test(document.getElementById("#inputIn").value));
 }
```

```html
<input id="#inputIn" />
<button id="#checkIt">check</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не видел ваш ответ. 
Я сделал несколько иначе. Не могли бы вы подсказать, как доработать мою регулярку, что бы если после запятой или точки можно было ввести только 6 цифр ещё? То есть, после ввода седьмой, чтобы выдавало уже false, при шестой еще true. Вот тут код :

https://jsfiddle.net/_jack/bgs7n895/383/

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ikO7RV/2